# Abstract class without any abstract method

Tags: c#

I am surprised to know that an abstract class in C# is possible with no abstract methods also.

```
abstract class AbstractDemo
{
 public void show()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("In Show Method"); 
   }
}
class MainDemo:AbstractDemo
{
 public static void Main()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("In Main Method");
 }
}
```

Any explaination ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sometimes you don't want to give the possibility to instantiate a class but you need this class as a base class for other classes.

The reason for choosing abstract classes over interfaces is that you can provide some basic implementation.

Comment: Okay this means we can use such an abstract class just as a marker class for other classes.

Comment: Yes indeed - but if you do not need an implementation you can use interfaces instead.

Comment: But you can derive with empty body so what have you achieved by forcing the user to do that? Also C# 8 allows for default implementation in interface classes. So I think where you would use abstract classes is when you need to have some instance fields.

Comment: @pooya13 Not sure I understand your point WRT deriving with empty body. WRT default implementation, you are correct. The answer was written long before C# 8

Comment: Never mind that. Understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

This is entirely valid, and occasionally useful if you want to provide event-like behaviour: provide an abstract class with all the "event handlers" implemented as virtual methods with a default behaviour of doing nothing.

I've also personally used this a lot for abstract remote API client classes where all methods throw exceptions: they're abstract for the purposes of test doubles, expecting our implementations to be the only *production* implementations, but allowing users to create their own test doubles either by hand or via mocking frameworks. Making the methods virtual instead of abstract means that new RPCs can be added without that being a breaking change.

A derived class can then override *some* of the methods, but doesn't have to override any specific one, because nothing's abstract. It still makes sense for the class to be abstract because an instance of the base class would be pointless (as everything would be a no-op).

This pattern is much more common in Java than C#, however - as in C# you'd normally just use "proper" events.

Comment: The only answer here without circular reasoning (i.e. saying it is possible because it is possible, instead of explaining the why) I would only say that it would have been nice to clearly state that this is pretty useless in C# if that is the case, and if not give an example use case

Comment: @pooya13: I've now added an example (and as it happens, I wouldn't have been able to provide that example 11 years ago...)

Comment: Thanks. BTW I just did a double take after seeing your score. I wasn't sure if I saw the "m" right!

Answer (score 5):

An abstract class is a class that must be extended before it can be used. This does not it any way mean that the function themselves must be abstract.

Take for example an Animal class

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    void Move()
    {
        //whatever
    }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    void Swim()
    {

    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    void Bark()
    {

    }
}
```

All animals can move but only the fish can swim and the dog can bark.

Or for a real life example. I have an Asp.net MVC base controller I use in my application. It has some basic methods I need very often like GetCurrentUser() and a function I wrote to help with localization. It also takes care of tracking so I don't have to rewrite that code in all of my controllers. The class has about 200 lines of code but not a single abstract method.

Comment: Actually, I think you'll find most dogs can swim ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing abstract classes with interfaces. Interfaces can't have methods with body, abstract classes can. There are times when you want to prevent user from instantiating an object of a specific class; but still provide some base functionality for the classes that derive from it; this is what an abstract class is useful for.

Comment: What about an abstract class with absolutely no method. Not even the definition.

Comment: @Nadeem In that case it is almost the same as a "marker" interface (i.e. without anything, just to mark a class; note that FxCop suggests using Attributes instead). The difference is that you can only have one base class (such as your "marker abstract class"), but can implement many interfaces. So in that case an interface is usually better.

Comment: Yeah but suppose we want to have some attributes of the class and if we use interface then by default they'll be public which will violate basic data hiding principle of OOPS.

Comment: I think your answer is outdated as interfaces CAN have default implementations since C#8.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is just a base for other classes and it does not have an full usablility - in other words as a base itselfe is not usable at all then you want to prevent from creating instances of it. In this case you can make abstract class without abstract members.

Answer (score 0):

You could use abstract keyword on a class just to signal the compiler that it can only used inheriting from it, and not directly; In this case you are not oblied to put abstract member on the class.

This is equivalent to put in the class only one protected constructor, but using abstract is more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

No better explanation than MSDN it self
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645615(v=VS.71).aspx

> - An abstract class cannot be instantiated directly, and it is a
>     compile-time error to use the new
>     operator on an abstract class. While
>     it is possible to have variables and
>     values whose compile-time types are
>     abstract, such variables and values
>     will necessarily either be null or
>     contain references to instances of
>     non-abstract classes derived from the
>     abstract types.
> - An abstract class is permitted (but not required) to contain abstract
>     members.
> - An abstract class cannot be sealed.

Answer (score 0):

We have heard that in abstract class, there must be an abstarct member. But when I compile the abstarct class without an abstract method, it compiles. It gives me surprise. Now I am unable to find the article which explain exact behavior of an abstarct class.